# React Native Touch Through Flatlist

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, flatlist

For
`"react-native": "^0.70.5"`

Requirement:

- `Flatlist` as an overlay above Clickable elements
- `Flatlist` header has a transparent area, with `pointerEvents="none"` to make the elements below clickable and yet allow the `Flatlist` to scroll.
  [image]

Issues with some possible approaches

1. `pointerEvents="none"` doesn't work with `Flatlist`, as internally how Flatlist is built it will block the events at all values of `pointerEvents`. It's the same with `Scrollview` as well.
2. [react-native-touch-through-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-touch-through-view) (the exact library I need) doesn't work with RN 0.70.2, library is outdated. After fixing the build issues, touch events are not propagating to the clickable elements.
3. Created a custom component `ScrollableView`, as `pointerEvents` with `View` work well. With this adding `pointerEvents` to `none` on parts of the children, lets the touch event to propagate to elements below.

- *This is working well on Android, but failing on iOS.*
- *Also the scrolling of the view is not smooth.*
- *Requires further handling for performance optimisation for long lists*

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, PanResponder, Animated } from 'react-native';

const ScrollableView = ({children, style, onScroll}) => {
    const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const lastScrollY = useRef(0);
    const scrollYClamped = Animated.diffClamp(scrollY, 0, 1000);

    const panResponder = useRef(
        PanResponder.create({
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
            onPanResponderMove: (_, gestureState) => {
                scrollY.setValue(lastScrollY.current + gestureState.dy);
            },
            onPanResponderRelease: (_, { vy, dy }) => {
                lastScrollY.current += dy;
                Animated.spring(scrollY, {
                    toValue: lastScrollY.current,
                    velocity: vy,
                    tension: 2,
                    friction: 8,
                    useNativeDriver: false,
                }).start();
            },

        })
    ).current;

    const combinedStyle = [
        {
            transform: [{ translateY: scrollYClamped }],
        },
        style
    ];

    return (
        <Animated.View
            {...panResponder.panHandlers}
            pointerEvents="box-none"
            style={combinedStyle}
        >
            {children}
        </Animated.View>
    );
};

export default ScrollableView;
```

Any solution to any of the above three approaches is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ui.gorhom.dev/components/bottom-sheet/components/bottomsheetflatlist

```
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useMemo } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import BottomSheet, { BottomSheetFlatList } from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet";

const App = () => {
  // hooks
  const sheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);

  // variables
  const data = useMemo(
    () =>
      Array(50)
        .fill(0)
        .map((_, index) => `index-${index}`),
    []
  );
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ["25%", "50%", "90%"], []);

  // callbacks
  const handleSheetChange = useCallback((index) => {
    console.log("handleSheetChange", index);
  }, []);
  const handleSnapPress = useCallback((index) => {
    sheetRef.current?.snapToIndex(index);
  }, []);
  const handleClosePress = useCallback(() => {
    sheetRef.current?.close();
  }, []);

  // render
  const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({ item }) => (
      <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      </View>
    ),
    []
  );
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Snap To 90%" onPress={() => handleSnapPress(2)} />
      <Button title="Snap To 50%" onPress={() => handleSnapPress(1)} />
      <Button title="Snap To 25%" onPress={() => handleSnapPress(0)} />
      <Button title="Close" onPress={() => handleClosePress()} />
      <BottomSheet
        ref={sheetRef}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        onChange={handleSheetChange}
      >
        <BottomSheetFlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(i) => i}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
        />
      </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 200,
  },
  contentContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  itemContainer: {
    padding: 6,
    margin: 6,
    backgroundColor: "#eee",
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Flatlist for this, you may need to do this approach, because it seems like the problem is in the display of the elements

Use bottom sheet library [here](https://ui.gorhom.dev/components/bottom-sheet/)

Use this the library [FlashList](https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/) which is faster and more customizable that Flatlist.

the benefit of using these libraries is that you don't need to do your own animation and it would save you a lot of issues/bugs that you could face, and it would fix the issue you are facing since both libraries support and tested on android/ios

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35497399)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel giving the code won't help, because in this case the user has to learn the library so giving the code won't help at all, those library need to be studied and customized based on requirements that the user need, so basically giving a copy/past code won't help. 
this is a direction in the right place, not a code teaching.

Comment: The expectation on Stack Overflow is that you don't just link to libraries, you need to demonstrate how the library can be used to address/solve the question.

Comment: in that case, i will make some kind demo code.
thanks for elaborating.